# SharePoint Online calculated column formula error

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, error, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

I would like to create a simple calculated field, that returns a text if a value is greater than another. Column `[Bruttó összeg]` is number type. I just copied the formula from the official Microsoft site, but still getting the error message:

"syntax error or not supported".

What should I do?

[image: calculated field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula syntax seems correct to me. Try using below formula:

```
=IF([Bruttó összeg] <= 100; "Within budget"; "Over budget")
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (It is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case you have to use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Thank you, semicolon was the trick.